# Waiting for user to press a button in Swift 2

Tags: ios, uibutton, ibaction

In one function in my Swift code, I need to wait until user presses a button. Otherwise, I just do nothing. How do I do this? Maybe button press triggers some event I can catch.

P.S. Due to structure of my code, doing what I want on this button press (like @IBAction) is not an option!

Comment: Button presses do trigger some event; the @IBAction method associated with their toucUpInside event. Explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve and why you think you can't use an action method.

Comment: Look. I want my main game function (called when i press "Start Game" button) to call 2 functions in loop, unless the game end condition is true. One function is computer's turn, the other is user's turn. I want the user's turn function to wait until user presses one of four buttons and then I can do some actions based on what button he press

Comment: You say I can check for `oneButton.touchInside == true` or smth like this?

Comment: No. Mobile apps are written to be responsive to user actions. In your ibaction you execute your user turn code. Once that is done you execute the computer turn function then you do nothing. When the user interacts with the button again then you run the next turn and so on

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global boolean value such as `var buttonPressed = false` and then, in the IBAction of the button (When you click it):

```
if buttonPressed = false{
       buttonPressed = true
}
```

And in the method you want to call when the button is pressed, just ask if buttonPressed is true.
Try that and tell me if it worked

Comment: That will be problematic because what I have is a turn-based game and I have 4 buttons. I want to get user input (numbers 1, 2, 3 or 4) and based on what button user pressed do things. I have a main procedure (game) - it checks for game end condition and if its false makes a computer turn and then must wait until user presses one of four buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can set the user interaction to `false` by default of your main `UIView` (usually the `UIViewController` view)

```
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

and when you have the action of button you set the user interaction to `true`.

```
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be too late but personally, there are two way you can achieve this.

1. Add Observer
2. Use delegate pattern so whenever user tap a button you notify your delegate